# Otimizar o código em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo, otimização

Salve salve!

Estou iniciando na programação em Java. Gostaria de pedir ajuda para otimizar ou deixar o código mais enxuto, com as devidas boas práticas. Já tentei otimizar com o pouco conhecimento que tenho da linguagem mas não consegui.

Dito isto, criei um algoritmo para resolver um pequeno problema: Dado um array, crie um programa para selecionar o maior e o segundo maior elemento do array, e em seguida exiba a diferença desses dois valores.

```
static void maxValues(int array[]) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array.length - 1 && array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    int maxValue = array[array.length - 1];
    int minValue = array[array.length - 2];
    int difference = maxValue - minValue;
    System.out.printf("\nMaior valor: %d\nSegundo maior valor: %d\nDiferença: %d", maxValue, minValue, difference);
}
```

Comment: Acho mais legível quando parênteses são colados ao que está fora e separado por espaço ao que há dentro (tipo seu `static void maxValues(int array[]) {` prefiro `static void maxValues( int array[] ){` e `` seria `for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){`, não acha melhor?), a não ser que seja muito curto (tipo `f(0)` mas dá dúvida entre `f(0,0)` e `f( 0 , 0 )`).

Comment: O mesmo pode valer para outros operadores, como colchetes e chaves. Outra coisa que prefiro é espaço antes e depois de `;` principalmente dentro de parênteses mas também em assignments. Também prefiro `=` e outros operadores somente com espaços antes e depois dele em trechos muito curtos, tipo `int i = 0 ;` ou `int i=0 , j=0 ;`. Em caso de expressões que considero muito longas, prefiro dividir em parênteses e formatar dentro deles individualmente. O resultado pode ser tipo `if(( array[j] < array.length-1 )&&( array[j] > array[j+1] )){`.

Comment: Tudo isso visando facilitar a separação dos símbolos e expressões, é uma forma de deixar mais legível, mais enxuto.

Comment: Por outro lado, o que não mais é opinião e gosto e sim é certamente assumido como boa prática é a diferenciação de campos e métodos que são de objeto e os que são de classe pela primeira letra: iniciada em minúscula é de objeto e em maiúscula, de classe (static). Então a função em Java, que é método estático, seria `MaxValues`.

Comment: Não sei se acesso a propriedade `length` é mais lento que variável local, se for o caso poderia salvar `int aLength = array.length ;` e passar a acessar `array.length` lá.